# How to change Pepper robot language inside application?

Tags: nao-robot, pepper

I want to use Finnish language inside my application.

[image]

Set language is set as Finnish.

[image]

When I try to run this:

[image]

How can I use Finnish language?

Comment: It doesn't matter what you have specified in Choregraph's project properties. The language must be installed, that's all.

Comment: @moderator: this question should have the tag "naoqi" as it's not robot specific.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the app cannot be launched because you authorized only Finnish. If you start your behavior by a "set language" I'm guessing it's because your robot is originally speaking a different language?

Try authorizing the language that Pepper is speaking *when you launch the behavior*.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the Finnish language on Pepper on first need to install the corresponding language package on your robot.
You can send this request to the Customer Support team [here](https://www.ald.softbankrobotics.com/en/about-us/contact).

Comment: True, but the Set Language box will turn red if the language is not installed, so that's a nice indicator.

Answer (score 0):

That is all about your robot default language.Example if its English you must also add English on your 'Set Language' section.

Answer (score 0):

AFAICS, there are the following prerequisites:

1. The language must be installed. How to: http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-8/family/nao_user_guide/setting_language_nao.html
2. In the project properties in Choregraphe, the desired language must be checked as one of the supported languages.
3. Set the robot language to the desired language, too. In case the default language is still English, also the English checkbox has to be checked.